# how to find the empty spot in a row?

Tags: combinatorics

I am suppose to put a group of people (given at run-time) in to a 2 dimensional array of spot, group together in a row randomly(find out all possible positions and randomly pick one)

To start of, I wanna try in an array first

if I have an array of spots of size 10 like below

```
spots[occupied,open,open,occupied,occupied,occupied,open,open,open,open]
```

to put 2 people

Is there a particular algorithm to do this kind of problem?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in python:

```
seats =["occupied","open","open","occupied","occupied","occupied","open","open","open","open"]

def empty(seats,index,count):
  if count == 0:
     return True
  else:
     return (seats[index] == "open") & empty(seats,index+1,count-1)

def findEmpty(seats,count):
  result = []
  for (i=0;i<seats.size-count+1,i++)
    if empty(seats,i,count):
      result.append(<list of consecutive numbers from i to i+count>)
  return result


print findEmpty(seats,2)  

>>>[[1, 2], [6, 7], [7, 8], [8, 9]]
```

here's another approach, its a little more efficient:

```
seats = ["occupied","open","open","occupied","occupied","occupied","open","open","open","open"]
//counts the number of consecutive free seats starting at position index
def countEmpty(seats,index):
    if index >= len(seats) or seats[index] == "occupied":
        return 0
    return 1 + countEmpty(seats,index+1)

def findEmpty(seats,count):
    result = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(seats)-count+1:
       c = countEmpty(seats,i)
          if c>=count:
             for (j=i;j<i+c-count+1;j++):
                result.append(<list of consecutive numbers from j to j+count>)
       i += 1 + c
    return result

print findEmpty(seats,2)
>>>[[1, 2], [6, 7], [7, 8], [8, 9]]
```

and finally, if you did choose to use python you could do it in one line:

```
seats =["occupied","open","open","occupied","occupied","occupied","open","open","open","open"]
count = 2    
print [range(i,i+count) for i in range(len(seats)-count+1) if all([seats[j]=="open" for j in range(i,i+count)]) ]
>>> [[1, 2], [6, 7], [7, 8], [8, 9]]
```

Comment: thanks for help..Can you give me the pseudo code? I dont know too much Python

Comment: i changed the lines where "range" was referenced, everything else is should be self explanatory. let me know if it isn't

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code:

```
//Create 2 lists of blocks, both empty: tmp and final
List tmp=new List;
List final=new List;

//Cycle the seats
for (int i=0;i<length(seats);i++) {
    //If the seat is occupied, start over
    if (seats[i]==occupied) tmp.empty();
    else {
        //Cycle existing block candidates, add free seat
        foreach (ref block in tmp) {
            block.add(seats[i])
            if (length(block)>=people_count) {
                //HEUREKA, got a fitting block: Move it to the final list
                tmp.remove(block)
                final.add(block)
            }
        }
        //Start a new block with this seat
        tmp.add(new block(seats[i]));
        //Read below for this edge case
    }
}
```

final now has the blocks.

If you allow the edge case of people_num being 1, you have to check for a complete block at the position indicated in the pseudocode

Answer (score 0):

I shall use *Mathematica* code but I believe you can follow the logic.

Starting with:

```
dat = spots[occupied, open, open, occupied, occupied, occupied, open, open, open, open];
fill = {"Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie", "Delta", "Echo", "Foxtrot"};
```

First find a random permutation of the list `fill` (it is easy to find an algorithm on StackOverflow):

```
randomfill = RandomSample @ fill
```

> {"Delta", "Echo", "Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie", "Foxtrot"}

Then "map" a function onto each element of the `spots` list, and if the element is `open` return the next value from the `randomfill` list, else return the element unchanged:

```
i = 1;
If[# === open, randomfill[[i++]], #] & /@ dat
```

> spots[occupied, "Delta", "Echo", occupied, occupied, occupied, "Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie", "Foxtrot"]